# Jenkins ssh remote host connection fails

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins

after upgrading jenkins due to security informations, the ssh remote host connection is not working anymore. The credentials (private keys) were migrated based on a update of the ssh credentials plugin, but i always get "Can't connect to server" error. I also tried to delete the old credentials and create new ones but this does not work. Did anyone of you experience the same error after updating the plugins?

Jenkins Version: 2.129

SSH Credentials Plugin: 1.14

SSH plugin: 2.6.1

[image]

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the error message correct ? Can you connect to the remote server with ssh ?
If not, the issue is not related to jenkins. See if the ssh server is running, and see if there are any firewall rules that would block incoming connections.

Comment: On the same server i have an ssh tunnel to the remote using the same private key. So the access to the remote with this key should be no problem. The problem started to occour after updating some of the plugins yesterday.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with SSH for the last few weeks. I'm using the SSH Credentials Plugin and the Publish over SSH plugin; downgrading them hasn't helped though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue while integrating with SSH server. I followed the below steps:

- Deleted old credentials.
- Deleted the file var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts
- Generated private key using command `ssh-keygen -f remote-ki -m PEM` - Make sure your private key should start with `------BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY------` instead of `------BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY------`
- Updated Dockerfile to reflect the new name change as in my case, the last private key name was remote-key.
- Copied new private key over `docker cp remote-ki jenkins:/tmp/remote-ki`
- `docker-compose up --build`

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: via command line, jenkins had access to my gitlab server:
jenkins@ACSVM:/home/jenkins/workspace/CheckMyMergeRequest$ ssh git@lcgit
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Jenkins!
Connection to lcgit closed.

Via the web interface, not:
stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
git@lcgit: Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Downgrading https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin to 1.13 fixed it for me.

This problem came up after upgrading my jenkins server from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 .

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues as well, even after downgrading my ssh credentials plugin. What worked for me was creating another private key in my machine I intended to log on to. I'll share this link here for anyone having similar issues.

https://linuxtechlab.com/how-to-easily-add-ssh-credentials-on-jenkins-server/

Answer (score -2):

I had this same error [**Can't Connect to Server**].
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfZcE.png
This error is due to Port 22 not enabled in your Jenkins.

You must add following command in your Dockerfile which [enables Jenkins to access port 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb83d.png).

```
EXPOSE 22
```

I hope it works fine.